# how to setup VPS domain registered via different service?

Tags: apache-httpd, hostname, domain, vps

I have a domain that was registered with network solutions and my vps is hosted via hostWinds.  I got a cheap/budget VPS because I'm a developer by trade and would rather know how to set all this stuff up manually rather than a managed service.

So, my domain, for example `abc.com` on network solutions, I pointed it to the two nameservers provided to me by hostWinds.  Next, I added some Virtual Host configuration in my apache and restarted apache as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@abc.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abcdotcom
  ServerName abc.com
  ServerAlias www.abc.com
  ErrorLog logs/abc-error_log
  CustomLog logs/abc-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart apache, and try it all - but I am getting the `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

I don't have CPanel, and I don't want it.  This should be fairly simple and I'm thinking I'm missing something small - what am I missing ?

I already have a name server - it seems the part where the name server forwards the request to MY machine is missing - how and where do I configure that?  I don't see it anywhere in the place where I manage my VPS account (just a basic web page, not a console or panel).

If i navigate to my IP address instead of using the domain name, apache serves up the basic HTML page I created for starters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all DNS and HTTP are different services.

So it is possible to run your DNS at one provider and have an hosted http server on another provider.

The only thing to setup is to edit your dns map so that abc.com A entry points to the ip of your vps server and you can also have a cname entry for www.abc.com pointing to abc.com.

But it is surely not mandatory to delegate the dns management from your dns provider to your vps provider.

In my own case, my dns provider is godaddy.com, my mail provider is gmail, and my hosting company is online.fr.... 
All i do is editing my domaine zone file at godaddy.com management interface to point out the dns entry to the right IP.

Comment: Thank you @netmonk - in my research, that is exactly what I was thinking but was not sure.  But in the process of providing 2 name server addresses, shouldn't HostWinds also provide the ability to add an A-record (to configure their name server to resolve my host name to my machine) - or is that done on my VPS using bind/dns zones?

Comment: I guess they should provide such service. Find a way on their board to edit your zone.

Comment: sadly they do not provide such a service. I'll have to try and find a way to create/bind a DNS zone and (possibly) provide an A-record someplace?  TBD...